# Multiple Hosted Zone VS Single hosted zone AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I recently used Amazon Route53 for routing my domains and I needed to route around 15 subdomains. I had 2 options to add subdomains:

1. Create a hosted zone for each subdomain and then add NS record in the parent domain.
2. Just create A record for all subdomains.

I tried both and both are working just fine. What are the pros/cons of using each option?

Comment: Not different than when NOT using AWS, which makes your tagging quite obviously irrelevant. Those are DNS basics.

Answer (score 0):

Hosted zones for subdomains are used for cases where you want to have a subdomain run on Route53 *without having to move the whole domain*. By adding extra nameservers for the subdomain(s) to the Route53 nameservers in the parent domain's DNS settings, you can manage the subdomain in Route53. This is not meant for cases where all domains are running on Route53.

You could use this, for instance, in cases where you don't have ownership over the whole domain, but would like to make regular changes to the subdomain.

Also, you pay the hosted zone fee for all 15 subdomains.